# What does "Public Web Files Directory" mean in the PHP Pear installer?

Tags: php, apache, installation

Two other users posted the same question:

[Installing pear path definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898232/installing-pear-path-definitions): "...what [is]...Public Web Files directory...?"

> "Directory where files for web applications get installed to. [...] When you use such a package/application, you need to point your web server's document root directory to it."

[Why does PEAR get installed to my user directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481165/why-does-pear-get-installed-to-my-user-directory)

> "Usually it will be something like /opt or /usr/local which will be accessible to all users."

The */usr/local* path is where you install workstation apps for a system-user. *Server's document root directory* is for 'the world' to access. Strangely, `go-pear.phar` installer uses the $prefix var for both locations, but the wording implies different contexts.

I understand you can change this here in the installer and after installation, but it raises the questions, Should all Pear files be in the server's root directory? If Paer tries to use these php files outside of the public directory (ex. /usr/local) is this going to cause problems. For example with SELinux's httpd context, `httpd_sys_content_t?

*What does "Public Web Files Directory" mean in the PHP Pear installer* when *.php files aren't processed by the PHP parser outside of a server's root directory?

Answer (score 0):

It can create problems in some security contexts (selinux, suPHP, open_basedir, etc). You can get aound these, tho. And as long as your permissions and restrictions are set properly, it's not a big deal.

You can also install PEAR anywhere and then just append the path to your PEAR directory by using [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/de/function.set-include-path.php). It can work well that way, you just might not be able to update it using the CLI.